# Excel upload not showing decimals

Tags: java, excel

I have a JSP page where all my columns are formatted to decimal places. I use the same code for the excel upload through another JSP but the same code but when the data gets uploaded to excel the decimal digits is neglected for whole numbers as follows:

```
eg: 1.00 shows as 1
1.32 shows 1.32
0.00 shows 0
```

But as per requirement I should show the exact values as in UI ie. 0.00...

The Excel file is created 'on-the-fly' and so formatting needs to be applied without accessing the workbook manually.

Comment: Sounds like an excel issue maybe you can change the formatting in excel...

Comment: Are you creating a .csv file?

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/decimalformat.html

Comment: Can you treat the values as a String? Is the excel file already built or your creating it on the fly?

Comment: @ brso05 its a .xls file. @Abercrombieande Its created on the fly.

Comment: I tried using formatKey="defaultCurrencyFormat" format="0.##" but wouldnt work

Comment: There is probably a way to specify formatting in the .xls file itself I am not familiar with how to do this but you could google it...alternatively once in excel you could probably format to 2 decimal places

Comment: @brso05. Since its generated on the fly i want to do it from java side.

Comment: Ya that would be ideal...like I said there is probably some way to specify it when you create the .xls file

Comment: Excel will create the new workbook with standard "General" formatting so unless you pass each value as a string with an apostrophe `'` at the beginning, Excel will interpret the current data as a number, and as such will not show leading or trailing zeros. If you pass it as a string it will display correctly, but you won't be able to use the values in calculations.

Comment: What are you using to generate .xls file apache poi?

Comment: Since it is created on the fly I am not sure how you would do that other than treat the data as strings. We always have to use csv files here since depending on the excel version it formats numbers and dates differently

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible in your case... I would create a blank excel file with a macro that applies formatting on open "Private Sub Workbook_Open() do formatting". Every time your program runs start with the template but save it as a different name.

Answer (score -1):

Change the format to Decimal or Number (with 2 decimal places), alternatively post the code that you are using. Unless you pass each value as a string prefixed with an apostrophe this isn't possible.